# pgf math is not returning the correct results

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I have in `\pgfmathsetmacro`s some stored variables.  I checked that math on Mathematica when the plotted points came back wrong.  `\pm\infp` is approx `\pm 1.51022` and `\pm\infn` is approx `\pm 0.46823`.  Then I need to determine their corresponding `y` values.  The equation is `x^2exp(-x^2)`.  It appears that everything is set up correctly, but the plot only shows one point at around `(-3, 0)` which isn't in the ball park.  Since everything appears correct, I am not sure what is going on or wrong.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infp}{sqrt(5 + sqrt(17))/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infn}{sqrt(5 - sqrt(17))/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yp}{(\infp)^2*exp(-(\infp)^2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{(\infn)^2*exp(-(\infn)^2)}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin = -3,
    xmax = 3,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = .5,
    xlabel = {x},
    ylabel = {y},
    ytick = {0.4},
    unit vector ratio = 1 1 1
    ]
    \addplot[blue, smooth] gnuplot[domain = -3:3, samples = 500]
    {x^2*exp(-x^2)};

    \foreach \x/\y in {\infp/\yp, -\infp/\yp, \infn/\yn, -\infn/\yn}{
      \begingroup\edef\temp{%
        \endgroup\noexpand\filldraw[red] (\x, \y) circle[radius = 0.025];}
      \temp
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `-x^2=(-x)^2` or `-x^2=-(x^2)` ? Obviously `power` takes precedence over `minus` in normal math, but I do not think it is well defined in inline notation.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen The equation is x^2*exp(-x^2) so it is set up correctly for the math.

Comment: When I try to run this I get an error for the line containing `gnuplot`.  Is there something special I must do other than running `pdflatex` on the document file?

Comment: @A.Ellett if you want to run the file, you will need to do shell escape.  Also, you may need to do a few runs since plot tables are generated.  If you use latexmk, then one calling to that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pgfplots` currently supports only the `axis cs` in order to write something into the axis.

Consequently, you need to write

`\filldraw (axis cs:\x,\y) ... ;`

and all is good.

Comment: Actually... well, I fear this is more my mistake/lack of courage. In the early days of pgfplots, I feared that reconfiguring the standard syntax `(\x,\y)` to use `axis cs` implicitly would cause lots of unanticipated bugs. Your question was the "kick-off" to convince me  that this needs to done and can be done and I made an item on my todo list. It is about time to revisit some of the older and complicated limitations of `pgfplots`.